# How to change the background color of input field when a button is clicked?

Tags: html, css, typescript, input, background-color

I would like to change my input field to change color when I click on a button. For extra information: the button's value itself changes when it is clicked.

This is the HTML I have right now:

```
<h2 class="label-custom">Tag</h2>
    <input class="input" [readonly]="isReadOnly" formControlName="tag" [placeholder]="'Enter your tags' | transloco">
    <button type="alter-button" class="alter-button" (click)="alter()">{{btnVal}}</button>
```

All the alter() function does is make the field readonly and change the button name. I can also change the color of the input field depending on what value the btnVal currently holds since the alter() function is called with each click. Is there a way I can change the background of the input field within the typescript file containing the alter() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `alter()` function to something like this

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h2 class="label-custom">Tag</h2>
    <input class="input" [readonly]="isReadOnly" formControlName="tag" [placeholder]="'Enter your tags' | transloco">
    <button type="alter-button" class="alter-button" (click)="alter()">{{btnVal}}</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  isReadOnly = false;
  btnVal = 'Alter';

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  alter() {
    this.isReadOnly = !this.isReadOnly;
    this.btnVal = this.isReadOnly ? 'Revert' : 'Alter';

    const inputElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.input');
    inputElement.style.backgroundColor = this.isReadOnly ? 'lightgray' : 'white';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just went to the CSS instead and created a second input type that was input:read-only for when the field was read only and that worked but I'll keep this in mind for next time :))

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved by pressing the tick on the left of the answer.